# Calculate probability distribution for n of participants in common to two parties given their size

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a set of parties $V=\left\{ {V_i, V_j,..., V_n}\right\}$. Each party has a corresponding attribute $S=\left\{ {S_i, S_j,..., S_n}\right\}$ indicating the number of people participating to the event. For each pair of events $V_i$ and $V_j$ I can infer the number of participants in common as $E_{ij}$, with $E_{ij}=0$ meaning no one participate to both parties.

Now I want to use my data to estimate, given $S_i$ and $S_j$, the probability distribution for $E_{ij}$ so to highlight which pair of $V_i$ and $V_j$ have a higher/lower $E_{ij}$ than expected given the data.

In other words, I would like to see for each $E_{ij}$ a probability distribution like this

[image]

which (I guess) should tell me that given $S_i$ and $S_j$, $E_{ij}$ as probability .2 of being 3, .23 of being 4, and so on. Then If the *real* value of $E_{ij}$ is, let's say, 10 I am in the position to tell that $E_{ij}$ has an unexpected value given the rest of the data.

Does it make sense doing it? How should I calculate the probability distribution for $E_{ij}$? Should I use a linear regression with $S_i$ and $S_j$ as independent variables?

NOTE: The figure was generated in R with the following code:

```
x = rbinom(100000, 20, 0.2)
plot(prop.table(table(x)),type="l")
```