# Regression analysis to estimate affinity or antipathy among celebrity wedding parties

Tags: regression, multiple-comparisons, graph-theory

Please consider the following plot of a graph:

[image: Plot 1]

Each node represents a wedding party while each edge is the relation between the two parties expressed in terms of the number of people who attended both weddings (with an edge of weight 0 in case of no common participant).

[image: Plot 2]

Each node $V_i$ has two attributes: **size** $S_i$, the number of people participating, and **time** $T_i$, the year the wedding took place.

Each edge $E_{ij}$ has one attribute: **weight** $W_{ij}$, the number of participants that $V_i$ and $V_j$ have in common.

I am interested in comparing each relation $E_{ij}$ against the whole dataset to understand which relation is stronger/weaker than expected. In other words, I want to obtain from the data a benchmark value — or the dataset "average" when controlling for the the two nodes attributes **size** ($S_i$ and $S_j$) and **time** ($T_i$ and $T_j$) — for each edge and then comparing the "average" to the real value of $W_{ij}$.

---

> **Put simply, what I want to infer from my data is whether the community participating to a weeding party $V_i$ shows an affinity or
>   an antipathy with the community participating to $V_j$.**

---

Because of my limited statistical tool-box, I though of simply proceeding with a regression analysis with **weight** (`shared_ppl` in the R script below) as response or dependent variable. As predictors I used `mult_size` (as $S_i \times S_j$) and `time_diff`(as $\left|T_i - T_j\right|$). As it is reasonable to assume, I want to test whether the **size** of the parties are correlated with **weight** and the difference in **time** are correlated with **weight**, and I want to estimate sign and quantity of both correlations.

In my simple example (see below for complete script) the linear regression

> $\mathbf{shared\_ppl} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \times \mathbf{mult\_size} +
> > \beta_2 \times \mathbf{time\_diff}$

will return the following coefficients:

```
Coefficients:
                 Estimate    Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -6395.7169331  3558.2955398  -1.797   0.0891 .
mult_size       0.0016097     0.0008846   1.820   0.0855 .
time_diff      -7.1564129     3.0076486  -2.379   0.0286 *
```

(NOTE: I know that the p-value for `mult_size` is slightly above the standard .05, but still let's considered it for the sake of the example as significantly correlated to `shared_ppl`)

Now I can "predict" for each $E_{ij}$ an expected $\hat{W}_{ij}$ and then compare it with the real $W_{ij}$. Specifically what I did was to calculate the difference (labelled as `offset` in the script) from the .95 confidence interval produced by the model. Then

1. a value of 0 would indicate that $W_{ij}$ of the relation $E_{ij}$
   is within the .95 confidence interval for $\hat{W}_{ij}$ as
   predicted by the regression analysis above
2. a value of -14.37 would indicated that $W_{kl}$ of the relation
   $E_{kl}$ is short of 14.37 people if compared to the .95 confidence
   interval for $\hat{W}_{kl}$.

The `offset` for each relation is plotted below

[image: Plot 3]

---

> Then, given my model above, I can infer from the data that
>
> 1. $V_i$ and $V_j$ do not show neither reciprocal affinity or
>      antipathy, while
> 2. $V_k$ and $V_l$ do show reciprocal antipathy

**Are my analysis and its conclusions correct from a statistical point of view?**

---

*For those who want to replicate the example in R here is the code*

```
library(igraph)

# Weddings from http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/10/02/famous-married-couples-ou_n_980125.html

# Create a full graph (all vertices are connected)
g <- graph.full(7)

# Assign attribute to graph
V(g)$name <- c("Ozzie\nAnd\nSharon Osbourne", 
            "Ali Hewson\nAnd\nBono", 
            "Jamie Lee Curtis\nAnd\nChristopher Guest",
            "Kevin Bacon\nAnd\nKyra Sedgwick",
            "Rita Wilson\nAnd\nTom Hanks",
            "John Travolta\nAnd\nKelly Preston",
            "David Bowie\nAnd\nIman")
V(g)$year <- c(2000,2001,2004,2005,2008,2009,2011)
V(g)$size <- c(200,300,80,90,100,400,500)
E(g)$weight <- c(100,20,11,10,20,0,21,6,10,70,40,100,8,3,0,2,14,100,100,150)

# Create layout for plot
layout <- layout.circle(g)

# Plot 1
plot(g,
     layout=layout,
     vertex.size=V(g)$size*0.1)

# Plot 2
plot(g,
     layout=layout,
     vertex.label="",
     vertex.size=V(g)$size*0.1,
     edge.label=E(g)$weight)

# Create data frame for analysis: one row for each pair of vertices
v_pairs <- get.edges(g, E(g))
v_pairs <- cbind(v_pairs, E(g)$weight)
v_pairs <- cbind(v_pairs, V(g)$year[v_pairs[,1]] * V(g)$year[v_pairs[,2]])
v_pairs <- cbind(v_pairs, abs(V(g)$year[v_pairs[,1]] - V(g)$year[v_pairs[,2]]))
v_pairs <- data.frame(v_pairs)

# Assign names to df
names(v_pairs) <- c("wedding_i", "wedding_j", "shared_ppl", "mult_size","time_diff")

# Regression analysis
model <- lm(shared_ppl~mult_size+time_diff,data=v_pairs)
options(scipen=999)
summary(model)

# Create data frame from prediction based on model
prediction <- predict(model,newdata=v_pairs,interval='confidence',level=.95)
prediction <- cbind(prediction, E(g)$weight)

# Function to calculate offset from .95 confidence interval of prediction
calc_offset <- function(x) {
  if (x[2]<=x[4]&x[4]<=x[3]) {return(0)}
  if (x[4]>x[3]) {return(x[4]-x[3])}
  if (x[4]<x[2]) {return(-(x[2]-x[4]))}
}

# Calculate offset based on formula above
offset <- round(as.numeric(apply(prediction, 1, calc_offset)),digits=2)

# Add results to graph
E(g)$offset <- offset

# Plot 3
plot(g,
     vertex.label=V(g)$size,
     layout=layout,
     vertex.size=V(g)$size*0.1,
     edge.label=E(g)$offset)
```

FINAL NOTE: This question is part of a line of thought which includes also these questions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/84339/35370), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/85561/35370), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/85820/35370) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/662772/79518).